# How to add classes to li elements using mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have this unordered list

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

How to add first and last classes to the first and last li element to look like this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="first">Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li class="last">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

er... in case you need some reuse, return them and apply the class in the process, relevant from a parent el (ul here):

```
var mylis = (function(el, decoration) {
    return el.getElements("li:first-child, li:last-child").map(function(li, i) {
        return li.addClass(decoration[i]);
    });
})(document.getElement("ul"), ["first", "last"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/Qy3KR/

else, just do (it will be a bit faster)

```
var els = document.getElements("ul li:first-child, ul li:last-child");
if (els.length === 2) {
    els[0].addClass("first"); els[1].addClass("last");
}
```

for mootools 1.1x:

```
var setFirstLast = function(el, decoration) {
    decoration = decoration || ["first", "last"];
    var lis = el.getElements("li");
    if (lis.legnth < 2)
        return;

    lis[0].addClass(decoration[0]);
    lis.getLast().addClass(decoration[1]);
};

setFirstLast(document.getElement("ul"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/Qy3KR/1/

and yes, make sure you run this in a domready callback

eg.

```
window.addEvent("domready", function() {

    setFirstLast(document.getElement("ul"));
});
```

Comment: this is also not working ;(. How come. I am pasting this script into script tags after mootools is loaded and no effect.

Comment: even when I use  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   
}
 window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
   var els = document.getElements("ul li:first-child, ul li:last-child");
    if (els.length === 2) {
     els[0].addClass("first"); els[1].addClass("last");
 }); 

  
 </script>

Comment: I am using MooTools 1.12 in Joomla 1.5

Comment: Should I put it in external file? And load it  this way?

Comment: you can put the function and the domready reference to it in an external file, yes. or add to an existing one. if you're on joomla, chances are that there are plenty of domready calls you can add your function call to.

Comment: It is loaded in sourcecode and still not working ;(. No calsses added in firebug or inspetor in chrome.

Comment: Thanks, finally the second code for mootools 1.1x you wrote is working ;). Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $elts = $$('ul > li');
$elts[0].addClass('first');
$elts.getLast().addClass('last');
```

API docs are a wonderful thing.

- [`Window.$$`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars)
- [`Element.addClass`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aaddClass)
- [`Array.getLast`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3agetLast)

---

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xnswq/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var $elts = $$('ul > li');
   $elts[0].addClass('first');
   $elts.getLast().addClass('last');
  
 </script> This code is not working for me ;(

Comment: Is there in mootools something like onload too?

Comment: It works for me - see my edit. What version of MooTools are you using? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: In firebug I do not see any classes appended. I have this code in my header after mootools is loaded.

Comment: I am running Joomla 1.5 with MooTools 1.12